# okta-signin-widget - I need to have back to sign in link on recovery link expired screen

Tags: reactjs, okta, okta-signin-widget

I have  requirement to keep a Back to Sign in link (Footer) when user accesses a link that is expired. 
At present it just displays the error msg that the link is expired. 
Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.I am using in a react js application.

[BackToSignin - Password Reset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukqS3.png)

[No link During Recovery token Validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Tq7.png)

Comment: Please share some codes and what you've done so far. It's certainly not clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please see the screen shots I have attached regarding the back to Login link that I am asking about. I don't have any custom code yet except what I see for okta live widget.